# Postfix mails bouncing for no reason

Tags: postfix, gmail, email-bounces

I have a Postfix server setup which works fine most of the time but between 100 - 200 mails gets deferred every day with the following errors:

```
status=deferred (lost connection with alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.142.27] while sending RCPT TO)

status=deferred (lost connection with mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.34] while sending message body)
```

That's around 10 % of all outgoing mails. Incoming mails works fine and all outgoing to domains on the local server works fine as well.

While troubleshooting, I found a certain mail that gmail keeps on bouncing, but if I compose a new mail to the exact same recipient google accepts it without any issues:

Mail that bounces:

```
Sep  3 13:08:04 mail postfix/smtp[2623]: 72A66184148: to=<user@gmail.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.79.27]:25, delay=2.5, delays=0.01/0/0.83/1.7, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.79.27] said: 554 5.7.1 9.9.9 (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Mail that gets delivered:

```
Sep  3 13:10:08 mail postfix/smtp[24005]: 38C47184147: to=<user@gmail.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.79.27]:25, delay=3.3, delays=0/0.01/0.82/2.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1378199356 hk5si14476075pac.241 - gsmtp)
```

If I forward the same mail that bounced to another domain on the local server it goes through fine.

But Yahoo bounces it with the following error:

```
host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.240] said: 554 5.7.1 9.9.9 (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

The size of both the emails are more or less same(less than 100KB) so that's not the issue here.

There is no firewall infront of the server. All DNS settings are correct, reverse DNS is setup properly and as I said, it's just certain mails that doesn't go through.

I spoke to the ISP and confirmed the MTU settings are okay.

Any suggestions?

**Update**
I manage a second mail server at a remote location and tried sending the mail that bounces to the remote domain. I ran tcpdump on the receiving end to see what is happening. While sending the mail that is bouncing, the server is sending RSET after it sends RCPT TO.

```
16:17:23.249320 IP mail.mydomain.com.47556 > mail.myremotemailserver.com.smtp: P 74:126(52) ack 228 win 123 E..h.R@.7...^.B2...}.....-B........{....... t...y...RCPT TO: ORCPT=

16:17:23.614527 IP mail.mydomain.com.47556 > mail.myremotemailserver.com.smtp: P 126:132(6) ack 242 win 123 E..:.T@.7..J^.B2...}.....-B........{....... t..vy...RSET
```

However, when I compose a new mail it sends DATA after RCPT to which is expected and the mail goes through fine:

```
16:19:20.911123 IP mail.mydomain.com.43064 > mail.myremotemailserver.com.smtp: P 73:125(52) ack 228 win 123 E..h..@.7.*_^.B2...}.8..;&J.`..4...{P@..... t...y...RCPT TO: ORCPT=


16:19:21.297598 IP mail.mydomain.com.43064 > mail.myremotemailserver.com.smtp: P 125:131(6) ack 242 win 123 E..:..@.7.*.^.B2...}.8..;&K.`..B...{t5..... t..ay...DATA
```

Doesn't make much sense to me..

Comment: I have found out that all such bounces has the error code: 554 5.7.1 9.9.9

Comment: When you connect from the server having the problem to port 25 of a remote server, what do you see?

Comment: `554 5.7.1 9.9.9` == "Message refused by Heuristic check" (aka, "stop spamming us")

Comment: Thanks Chris, but why do I get : 554 5.7.1 9.9.9 on some emails only? 

I have noticed this is mostly happening with emails that are forwarding other mails as attachment..

If the same sender sends another mail to same recipient, it goes through.

Comment: I couldn't figure this out, so in the end I configured this server to relay all mails to yahoo and gmail through a relayhost somewhere else. This is working fine! 

This is not a permanent solution so I'm still looking for suggestions.

Comment: This issue is back! Gmail has started rejecting most of the mails and there is this specific mail which is even bounced by my relayhost with the error code : 554 5.7.1 9.9.9! How can this happen? There is no ant-spam software on the relay host. It is just a postfix instance relaying mails from my mailserver.

Answer (score 2):

554 is a **permanent** error, as you're aware. This isn't some form of grey-listing test to see how you implement queueing.

As others have pointed out, 99.9% of 554's are issued because you message failed an anti-spam test. The fact that you get the 554 after the end of DATA suggests that there is something in the content of the message that they don't like, although the server *could* have already decided that it's going to reject your message much earlier than that and has been configured to wait until the end for various reasons (1. waste your time/bandwidth/resources, and 2. gather as much information about your message as possible).

The hardest part of these situations is that you're failing policies that are developed and enforced by the receiving end; they might be rejecting your message because the body has the word "apple" in it and the last octet of your IP address is a multiple of 3 for all we know. Highly unlikely, but possible.

Messages usually aren't rejected based on failure of 1 criteria, especially by "the big boys", so I would *guess* that you're failing multiple tests, but the only way to find out exactly (considering the lack of information in the rejection message) is to ask them unfortunately.

I found [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585?hl=en) for Google in relation to your problem which may be a good path to follow. I couldn't find a similar page for Yahoo at a quick look.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to see the spam assassin score for that particular message?
go on this website 
[spamscorechecker][1]

[1]: http://spamscorechecker.com/ send to them that message and another message which have been delivered so you can see the differences between them. Keep us update because I am curious to know what the problem is.

Comment: The link was useful. I got a 4.6/5 for the mail that was bouncing from yahoo. More info:

`3 spam rules triggered

1 RCVD_MAIL_COM Forged Received header (contains post.com or mail.com)
1 SUBJECT_FUZZY_TION Attempt to obfuscate words in Subject
2.6 DEAR_FRIEND Dear Friend? That's not very dear!`

These mails are going through okay when I use a relayhost.

Comment: Ah nice one, but 4.6/5 is still an high score and it is not good if you're going to send a lot of mails.!Try to follow the explanation on spam assasin page score and reduce your score.That should improve your delivery to the inbox folder.

Comment: This issue is happening again, now I can't forward the mail that is bouncing to spamscorechecker.com: `Sep 17 22:42:50 mail postfix/smtp[12871]: D1FEC184145: to=<10903@SpamScoreChecker.com>, relay=SpamScoreChecker.com[107.23.208.101]:25, delay=51, delays=0.01/0.01/4.7/47, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with SpamScoreChecker.com[107.23.208.101] while sending end of data -- message may be sent more than once)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like gmail et.al. think you are spamming, so it is throttling you to see if you retry. You said your rdns is properly configured but make sure that any SPF records for domains you are sending as denote you as an allowed sender for that domain. Check if your IP is on any blacklists using one of the free online tools and if it appears, request that the IP be removed from said list.

Comment: It is not just gmail. The same mail get bounced by yahoo and a few other mail servers. If I send another mail with different content, all the above servers accept the mail without any issues. IP is not in the blacklist. I have setup many mail servers in the past and have never used SPF records but never faced such issues. How import is it to set it up?

Comment: They can help but are not critical. I would try adding them; it may increase the trust mail providers have in emails originating from your server by adding accountability. Another similar tool that may boost trust is DKIM, both of which are relatively easy to configure with postfix. There is, however, certain content that gmail, yahoo or the like can never be convinced is legitimate and will always bounce like this.

Comment: @Debianuser "If I send another mail with different content, all the above servers accept the mail without any issues"... surely it's time to scrutinize the content?

Answer (score 0):

They suppose you are `spam`. Please reconfigure your `MTA` according to [spamhaus](http://www.spamhaus.org/) , Also check your MTA according to `Barracuda`.(Your `IP address` and so on.)